# Scroll to specific div when scroll down or scroll up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

On my site I have it so my scroll is locked:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and on click of buttons it scrolls to a certain div, all the divs are beneath each other, I would like to know if it is possible to check if the user 'tries' to scroll down or up, while scroll is locked, so if they try scroll down with the mouse wheel, I want to know how to do this so I can scroll down or up to the next div.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Javascript `window.onscroll` could be used for this but if you have something in place preventing a scroll then I don't think it will work. *Not 100% sure as I haven't locked the scroll and attempted to listen for scroll events* I would recommend displaying more relevant source code and your attempts.

Comment: As far as I know , scroll event wont be triggered if the main window has no scroll at all. A possible solution would be, instead of body, wrap the contents within the DIV, put a little scroll on the body and get going..

Comment: You might want to take a look at something like [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/).

Answer (score 0):

This will tell you if they are scrolling down or up. Then you would have to deal with the transition by yourself.

But in any case, if you are looking for a more tested solution, I would encourage you to use an already existent plugin such as [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) which will provide old browser compatibility, touch detection, **a proper solution for trackpads and Apple laptops/Magic Mouse**, resize support and a lot of other useful features.

```
addMouseWheelHandler();

function MouseWheelHandler(e) {
     // cross-browser wheel delta
     e = window.event || e;
     var value = e.wheelDelta || -e.deltaY || -e.detail;
     var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, value));


     //scrolling down?
     if (delta < 0) {
         console.log("scrolling down");
     }

     //scrolling up?
     else {
         console.log("scrolling up");
     }

     return false;
 }


 function addMouseWheelHandler() {
     if (document.addEventListener) {
         document.addEventListener('mousewheel', MouseWheelHandler, false); //IE9, Chrome, Safari, Oper
         document.addEventListener('wheel', MouseWheelHandler, false); //Firefox
     } else {
         document.attachEvent('onmousewheel', MouseWheelHandler); //IE 6/7/8
     }
 }
```